# Cosa significa "rimozione" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro *I migliori anni della nostra vita* di Ernesto Ferrero ho letto:

> Nessuno dei redattori capisce di conti, né vuole saperne qualcosa, per **rimozione** e viltà, oltreché per manifesta incompetenza.

Malgrado abbia cercato il vocabolo "rimozione" in parecchi dizionari, non riesco a capire il suo significato nella frase precedente. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credo che il termine venga qui utilizzato nella sua accezione psicoanalitica; prendo la definizione da Wikipedia https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rimozione:

> In psicoanalisi, la rimozione è un meccanismo psichico che allontana dalla coscienza desideri, pensieri o residui mnestici *(=riguardanti la memoria)* considerati inaccettabili e intollerabili dall'Io, e la cui presenza provocherebbe vergogna.

I redattori non sanno nulla, né vogliono saperne di conti perché hanno cancellato completamente ogni ricordo o studio fatto riguardo all'argomento.